# What is the difference between a writer monad and a list writer monad

Tags: functional-programming, monads

I was looking at the examples of writer monad to understand how it works and almost all of those looks like a list writer monad. I know a list writer monad is a type of writer monad. But what really is a writer monad in lay-mans terms.

Comment: Please,add the related language

Comment: Any language would be fine as I am looking more at the concept of it than the implementation.

Comment: Can you cite a reference for a "List writer monad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lay terms, the writer monad is the monad that lets you "write" items to a "log" while you produce a value. When you're done, you end up with the value you produced *and* the log that contains all the stuff you wrote. To put it another way, it is the monad whose side effects are "writing things to a log".

Let's make this more concrete with examples of both the list writer and the (generic) writer monads. I'll use Haskell here, since it is the original context in which [Monads for Functional Programming](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf) were described.

### The List Writer Monad

I assume that the "list writer" monad is one that logs an item (of some type we'll call `w`) into a list of items (of type `[w]`, of course). It also produces a value of type `a`. (See the note at the bottom if you get errors using this code yourself.)

```
newtype ListWriter w a = ListWriter { runListWriter :: ([w], a) }

instance Monad (ListWriter w) where
  return a = ListWriter ([], a)    -- produce an a, don't log anything
  ListWriter (ws, a) >>= k =
    let ListWriter (xs, a') = k a  -- run the action 'k' on the existing value,
    in ListWriter (ws ++ xs, a')   -- add anything it logs to the existing log, 
                                   -- and produce a new result value

-- Add an item to the log and produce a boring value.
-- When sequenced with >>, this will add the item to existing log.
tell :: w -> ListWriter w ()
tell w = ListWriter ([w], ())

ex1 :: ListWriter String Int
ex1 = do
  tell "foo"
  tell "bar"
  return 0
```

(NB: This is equivalent to `ex1 = tell "foo" >> tell "bar" >> return 0`, demonstrating the use of `tell` with `>>` to add an item to the log.)

If we evaluate `runListWriter ex1` in GHCi, we see that it wrote "foo" and "bar" to the log and produced the result value `0`.

```
λ> runListWriter ex1
(["foo","bar"],0)
```

### The (Generic) Writer Monad

Now, let's see how we turn this into the generic writer monad. The writer monad works with any sort of thing that can be combined together, not just a list. Specifically, it works with any `Monoid`:

```
class Monoid m where
  mempty :: m            -- an empty m
  mappend :: m -> m -> m -- combine two m's into a single m
```

Lists are a Monoid with `[]` and `(++)` as `mempty` and `mappend` respectively. A non-list example of a Monoid is sums of integers:

```
λ> Sum 1 <> Sum 2        -- (<>) = mappend
Sum {getSum = 3}
```

The writer monad is then

```
newtype Writer w m = Writer { runWriter :: (w, m) }
```

Instead of a list of `w`'s, we just have a single w. But when we define the Monad, we ensure that `w` is a `Monoid` so we can start with an empty log and append a new entry to the log:

```
instance Monoid w => Monad (Writer w) where
  return a = Writer (mempty, a)   -- produce an a, don't log anything
  Writer (w, a) >>= k =
    let Writer (x, a') = k a      -- we combine the two w's rather than 
    in Writer (w <> x, a')        -- (++)-ing two lists
```

Note the differences here: we use `mempty` instead of `[]` and `(<>)` instead of `(++)`. This is how we generalize from lists to any Monoid.

So the writer monad is really a generalization of the list monad to arbitrary things that can be combined rather than just lists. You can use lists with the `Writer` to get something (almost) equivalent to `ListWriter`. The only difference is that you have to wrap your logged item in a list when you append it to the log:

```
ex2 :: Writer [String] Int
ex2 = do
  tell ["foo"]
  tell ["bar"]
  return 0
```

but you get the same result:

```
λ>  runWriter ex2
(["foo","bar"],0)
```

This is because instead of logging "an item that will be put in a list", you are logging "a list". (This does mean that you can log multiple items at the same time by passing a list of more than one element.)

For an example of a non-list use of Writer, consider counting the comparisons a sort function makes. Each time your function make a comparison, you can `tell (Sum 1)`. (You can tell someone. Get it? Is this thing on?) Then, at the end, you'll get back the total count (i.e., the sum) of all of the comparisons along with the sorted list.

---

NOTE: If you try to use these `ListWriter` and `Writer` definitions yourself, GHC will tell you that you are missing `Functor` and `Applicative` instances. Once you have the `Monad` instance, you can write the others in its terms:

```
import Control.Monad (ap, liftM)

instance Functor (ListWriter w) where
  fmap = liftM

instance Applicative (ListWriter w) where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap
```

And likewise for `Writer`. I elided them above for clarity.